# SQL query that finds the names of the actors who are playing in "Action" genre

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am doing a small course in SQL during my academic degree, I am very new with this material.

---

Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies.

> Write in SQL query that finds the names of the actors who are playing in "Action" genre and that the actor Johnny Depp does not playing is those movies.

[image]

The tables:

```
Actors 
    ActorID      PK
    Firstname 
    LastName

Directors 
    DirectorID   PK
    Firstname 
    LastName

Genres 
    GenreID      PK
    GenreDescr 

Movies 
    MovieID      PK
    MovieName 
    Year

ActorsMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    ActorID      PK 

DirectorsMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    DirectorID   PK 

GenresMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    GenreID      PK
```

**My attempt:**

```
 SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
 FROM Actors
 INNER JOIN ActorsMovies ON Actors.ActorID= ActorsMovies.ActorID
 INNER JOIN GenresMovies ON ActorsMovies.MovieID=GenresMovies.MovieID
 GROUP BY GenreID
 HAVING GenreID='201' AND NOT IN Actors.ActorID='301855124' ;
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." Also, the HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
FROM Actors
INNER JOIN ActorsMovies t ON Actors.ActorID= t.ActorID
INNER JOIN GenresMovies ON t.MovieID=GenresMovies.MovieID
WHERE GenresMovies.GenreID = 201 and 
not exists (select b.movieid from actorsmovies b where b.ActorID=301855124 and b.movieid = t.movieid) ;
```

This query uses NOT EXISTS function that checks in each actor that answer your request that johnny depp doesn't play in that movie

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
 FROM Actors
 INNER JOIN ActorsMovies ON Actors.ActorID= ActorsMovies.ActorID
 INNER JOIN GenresMovies ON ActorsMovies.MovieID=GenresMovies.MovieID
 WHERE GenreID='201' AND Actors.ActorID<>'301855124' ;
```